# Problem while importing old android projects

Tags: android, android-studio

iam trying to import old android project but i face many problems

i have installed android support repository though android studio telling to install android support repository

build failed    10 s 513 ms
Run build   10 s 340 ms
Load build  5 ms
Configure build 302 ms
Calculate task graph    71 ms
Run tasks   9 s 950 ms
null
Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.
The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.4.2.

Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.4.0.
Required by:
    project :app

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
Open Android SDK Manager

Comment: by the way - iam a beginner in android using android studio version - 3.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Project which you have imported is having older dependencies.Hence that will not work with Latest android studio.

Also you need to replace your dependency declaration

**E.g.**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
```

Replace it with

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
```

Comment: thanks but there were more changes done migrated to androidx using refactor and solved 3 gradle warning because of incompatible build tool version and some obsolete warning solved